# iOS/Objective-C: Add badge to custom UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, badge

This is now very common but I cannot find a way to add a badge to a custom, or non-system, UIBarButton Item.

The following will add a badge to a systemUIBarButtonItem.  But it does not work for one created from an image, i.e. a custom one.  I would like to avoid creating a dependency on a separate class and would really like to find something similar to this that works for a custom button.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

This creates badge for systemButton such as a search button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(searchButtonPressed)];
int badgeint = 4;
NSString *badgestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",badgeint];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[searchButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.badgeValue = badgestring;
```

The same code for a custom button--there is no system button for notification so I need to use a custom image--does not produce the badge.

```
UIBarButtonItem *notificationButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"notification-32.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(notificationButtonPressed)];     
int badgeint = 4;
NSString *badgestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",badgeint];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[notificationButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.badgeValue = badgestring;
```

Note: the reason I have barbuttonitems is that sometimes I use more than one)

Thanks for any suggestions

EDIT:

I found out that I made a stupid error--I set the value two different times.  I thought the second would override the first, but apparently it confused it.  There is no difference between system and custom buttons.  I did discover, however, that if you have multiple buttons, the badge will always appear at the right of the group.  Using this method, you can't seem to put the badge on a bar button item second in from right for example.